# AWS authentication to Amazon Cognito

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-web-services, authentication, amazon-s3

I'm a newbie on mobile dev. I'm trying to authenticate to `Amazon Cognito`.
I first login to `Credentials Provider` using a username, pin, platform and deviceToken using custom services model - I then get identityId, endPoint and token back. I'm told that I need to swap the token I got back and refresh my credentials in order for me to be authenticated to `AWS Cognito` and `S3`. But all the process is confusing and have a lot of examples that are different.

I've created a SignInProvider, extending AWSSignInProvider to access the - (void) login: (void (^) (id result, NSError *error)) completionHanlder; I have my token, endpoint and identityId inside my login method..what do I do with the completion handler and whats next after.

```
@implementation SignInProvider

+(instanceType) sharedInstance{}

- (NSString) identityProviderName{}

- (AWSTask<NSString*>*) token{}

- (BOOL) isLoggedIn{}

- (NSSting*) userName{}

- (void) reloadSession{}

- (void) login: (void (^) (id result, NSError *error)) completionHanlder{

authRequest = [IMPCLDMobileAuthenticationRequest new];



     [authRequest setToken:@"930fc1b56d8ca19a84500f9a79af71b65f60331f0242ce4395cdf41186443692"];

        [authRequest setPassword:@"pin"];

        [authRequest setUsername:@"example@email.co.za"];

        [authRequest setPlatform:@"ios"];

        serviceClient = [IMPCLDImpressionInternalMicroserviceClient defaultClient];


        [[serviceClient mobileAuthenticationPost:authRequest] continueWithBlock:^id(AWSTask *loginTask)
     {


    //what to do here with my loginTask results (token, endpoint, identityId)

        }

    return nil;

    }
```

Comment: What is the task you are trying to accomplish? Upload something to an S3 bucket specific to the user? Upload/download things to the same bucket for the entire app regardless of which user it is?

Answer (score 2):

To swap/save token in `AWS` you need to do below in your `continueWithBlock`

```
[[serviceClient mobileAuthenticationPost:authRequest] continueWithBlock:^id(AWSTask *loginTask)
 {
     AWSSNSCreateEndpointResponse *response = loginTask.result;
     AWSSNSSubscribeInput *subscribeRequest = [AWSSNSSubscribeInput new];
     subscribeRequest.endpoint = response.endpointArn;
     subscribeRequest.protocols = @"application";
     subscribeRequest.topicArn = YOUR_TOPIC_ARN;
     return [sns subscribe:subscribeRequest];
 }] continueWithBlock:^id(AWSTask *task) {
     if (task.cancelled) {
         NSLog(@"Task cancelled");
     }
     else if (task.error) {
         NSLog(@"Error occurred: [%@]", task.error);
     }
     else {
         NSLog(@"Success");
     }
     return nil;
 }];
```